# Линукс для изучения Руби

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian

Решил изучать руби, а конкретно его фреймворк "рельсы". На форумах читал, что для этих целей лучше установить себе какую-то unix ОС. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли разница какой дистрибутив устанавливать? Не могу определиться между дебианом и убунту (возможно, есть какой-то дистрибутив более подходящий для этого, о котором я не знаю).

Comment: если выбираете между дебианом и убунтой - берите убунту. А потом, позже, если линукс приживется, то сами поймете, нужен ли дебиан или убунта или какой то другой дистрибутив (может арч, генту или LFS).

Comment: + за выбор `Ubuntu`

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо

Comment: Ещё гляньте на Linux Mint, на мой вкус покрепче убунты будет. У него есть редакции на основе Ubuntu (основные) и Debian (LMDE). А там уже посмотрите, какой понравится больше. А если будете смотреть Ubuntu, посмотрите и редакции с другими рабочими столами: Kubuntu, Xubuntu и другие. Выбирайте **по вкусу**, а о вкусах тут не спорят.

Comment: Лёгким движением руки изучение руби превращается... Изучение руби превращается... Превращается изучение руби... В изучение линуха!

Comment: Минус бубунте, ф топку минт. Только RedHat. Вы же не для себя планируете делать программки на руби, а для какого-нибудь солидного заказчика. Поэтому и линухи надо подбирать соответствующие. Халявное ответвление от RedHat называется Fedora. Есть ещё халявный CentOS как бы клон RedHat. Как разбогатеете приобретёте RedHat.

Answer (score 2):

Линукс - это всё же не ОС, а ядро. Вам подойдёт любая [POSIX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) система.
 Даже на худой конец - MacOS (-: